# How to export a component properly using middleware component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to import a component to a main component, but i dont want to import the component directly. Instead what i want to do is to use a middleware component which will import and export the component and via that middleware component i want to import the said component in the main component include the associated css.

my structure is like this:

```
Main.tsx
components
  -- Index.tsx
    --core
      -- Button.tsx
      -- Button.css
```

Now i want to import `Button` in Main.tsx but using Index.tsx.

Like:

```
import {Button} from './components/Index.tsx'
```

Also in addition to that i also want to Button component to retain its `css`.

I tried using below code but that not working `'./components/Index.tsx'`:

```
import './core/Button.tsx'

export const Button;
```

I am using typescript so a typescript solution will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**It would be a bit cleaner if you structure your files/folders like this:**

```
Main.tsx
components
    --core
      --styles
         --Button.css
      -- Button.tsx
      -- index.ts
```

**And then in your index.ts:**

```
export * from './Button';
```

**And in your `MainComponent` you don't need to point directly to index.ts:**

```
import { Button } from './components/core'
```

**Or even bring it to a higher level:**

```
Main.tsx
components
    --index.ts
    --core
      --styles
         --Button.css
      -- Button.tsx
      -- index.ts
```

**So in the new index.ts you do:**

```
export * from './core';
```